# UE4 Navmesh isn't the same in viewport and in game

Tags: unreal-engine4, navmesh

### So I am making a navmesh in a scene which loads multiple levels, everything work except when the navmesh is rebuilt on startup it isn't the same as the one I see in the viewport and is way less accurate now for some reason(it is important to reload since multiple levels can be streamed but for testing purposes, I stream the same one that I see in the viewport), 2 links will be there with the viewport version and the in-game one when I simulate the game. The setting are the same in the project setting and on the actual RecastNavMesh and I can't find anything on the net refering to my problem.

[1] In viewport : https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWVRE.jpg
[2] In Game : https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0RdO.jpg